# HTMLでボタンを押すとHTMLを生成するようにする

Tags: html

HTMLでボタンを押すとHTMLを生成するようにするにはデータベースを生成するためのPHPとなにでできますか ？ JavaScriptでできますか？

追記

ウェブ上で おっしゃられているような日記帳のようなものをイメージしています

追記

1 PHP Java Python はどれか一つをもちいればいいのでしょうか ？ 2 配信用のサーバーはアマゾン レンタルサーバーなどでよろしいのでしょうか ？ 3 プログラムファイルを配置するパソコンは 中身 をサーバーに上げて代用することはできないのでしょうか ？ 4 サーバーサイド言語とCGI言語はちがうものでしょうか ？ 5 サーバーは ウェブ ドメイン データベース … という認識なのですが それらを自身でそろえて動かすことは可能でしょうか ？

Comment: こんにちは、はじめまして。質問の中身を整理させてください。まずHTMLの中にボタンを置きます。そのボタンを押すと、あたらしいHTMLができます、という形を考えていますか? 例えばインターネット上で使える日記帳のようなものを考えていますか? それとも自分のPCの中で完結するものを考えていますか? それを説明した内容を[編集]で文章に付け加えていただければ幸いです。

Comment: より具体的に実施したいことを記述いただくと良いかと思います。どういうユーザがいて、どういう動作をしてシステムがどういう画面を表示するかなどですね。

Comment: このサイトでは一般的に一問一答が基本で関連する質問であればいいのですが、あまりに多いと敬遠される形になります。多少面倒ですが、一問ずつ質問を投稿するようにお願いします。またQAサイトになりますので、体系的な知識を得るためにはいささが合わないと思いますので、ぜひ本や体系的にまとめられたWebサイトをご覧いただくほうが良いかと思います。

Answer (score 1):

はじめまして、こんにちは。

インターネット上で使える日記帳のようなものを作るには、何が必要かというご質問として理解しました。まず必要な知識という点で回答します。

- HTML *必須
- サーバサイド言語(PHP,JAVA,PYTHONなど) *必須
- DB(かファイル保存)に関する知識 *必須
- ウェブサーバーに関する知識 (とりあえず構成できればOK)

このほかにもいろいろ、ありますが必須の三つが分かればどうにかなります。これらを組み合わせて **ウェブシステム** を作ることになります。それぞれの役割は、HTMLが画面表示、DBが情報の保持、サーバサイド言語はそれらを制御するために用います。HTMLもサーバサイド言語から作りますのでとりあえずは何かサーバサイド言語を選びましょう。

続いて物理的(実態のあるもの)としては以下のものが必要になります。また

- 上記の環境が整った配信用のサーバー
- サーバーを操作しプログラムファイルを配置するためのパソコン

配信環境は仮にパソコンの上に構築して、動作を確認してからサーバーにコピーすることが多いです。

最後に、学びたい言語の、よいチュートリアルか入門書を当たられることをお勧めします。ウェブシステムに限るならPHPは確かにお勧めです。ただ情報が古かったりメンテナンスされてなかったり、有料であることも多いので注意して当たってください。

公式のチュートリアルを実際に動きを見ながら完了したあと、DBを使った日記帳や掲示板に関するチュートリアルを探してみてはどうでしょうか。

https://www.php.net/manual/ja/tutorial.php

#### コメントへのご質問の解

1 はいどれかを使えばいいです。目的からするとPHPが余計な情報がなく個人的にはお勧めです。 ？
2 はい。レンタルサーバーで構いません。無料で試せるところを探してはいかがでしょう。
3 あなたがプログラムをするためのコンピューターがあると便利です。サーバーとする端末でも作業はできますが。基本的には不便なのでやりません。
4 サーバーサイド言語という言葉に比べて、CGIはウェブサーバーを用いたより限定的な仕組みをいいます。CGIはそれを使うときに気にすればいいかと思います。
5 サーバーという言葉は通常何らかのサービスをクライアントに提供するコンピューターやプログラムのことをいいます。サーバーに含まれるソフトウェアはLINUX系のサーバーを借りれば通常あらかじめ入ってますし、入っていない場合も多くは無料で手に入れることができます。

ところで質問の形式についてですが、整理した内容を、質問欄に入力して、適宜回答に対しての評価をいれてもらえるとありがたいです。頂いた質問とその回答でサイトの価値が上がっていくと思いますのでよろしくお願いします。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます 認識としてはおおよそあっていました 追加で 1 PHP Java Python はどれか一つをもちいればいいのでしょうか ？ 2 配信用のサーバーはアマゾン レンタルサーバーなどでよろしいのでしょうか ？ 3 プログラムファイルを配置するパソコンは 中身 をサーバーに上げて代用することはできないのでしょうか ？ 4 サーバーサイド言語とCGI言語はちがうものでしょうか ？ 5 サーバーは ウェブ ドメイン データベース … という認識なのですが それらを自身でそろえて動かすことは可能でしょうか ？ 長くてすみません

Comment: コメントで答えるのは難しいので、質問を編集していただけますか? 回答に反映しておきます。

Comment: ありがとうございます 末尾の内容の仕方がわかりません

Comment: 本質問はクローズされているようですのでオープン後、または今後質問される際ご注意ください。

Comment: そうなんですね わかりました